# how can I adjust width of <p:column> in <p:panelGrid>?

Tags: primefaces

I used width attribute as 
 for all columns
but In display, columns are not adjusted.

Can i get in this way?
If, please guide me to achieve column widths as I desired.

Comment: When you are working with PrimeFaces your best solution is to get the manual and check to see what style classes it gives to its generated elements, then override them. Use firebug for that or something.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can either use a hard coded value:

```
<p:column style="width:20px">
```

or a percentage :

```
<p:column style="width:20%">
```

depending on what suits you best.

Comment: Also you can use `styleClass="table table-full"` by `table` is a general table-styling class (e.g. rounded corners in only 2 corners) and `table-full` is a style class for full width. `.table-full {width:100%;}` for example. :-)

Comment: with width:20%, can you center text

Answer (score 12):

you must to use columnClasses attribute and separate every column style with comma(,).
the code examples below show how to use columnClassess attribute.

in head tag:

```
<style type="text/css">
            .column1{width: 10px;height:auto}
            .column2{width: 5px;height:auto}
            .column3{width: 20px;height:auto}
           </style>
```

in body tag:

```
<p:panelGrid columnClasses="column1,column2,column3" columns="4" style="width: 100%" >  
                    <p:column></p:column>                        
                    <p:column></p:column>
                    <p:column></p:column> 
                    <p:column></p:column> 
                </p:panelGrid>
```

it is works with h:panelGrid  tag too.

Comment: Perfect, works even though I am not using <p:column>

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use ui-grid-col css class as described in [primefaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/grid.xhtml) . Where 12 = 100%

```
<div class="ui-grid ui-grid-responsive">
 <div class="ui-grid-row">
  <div class="ui-grid-col-2">
     <h:outputText value="To :" />
  </div>    
  <div class="ui-grid-col-4">
      <h:outputText value="#{bean.name}" />
  </div> 
</div>
<div class="ui-grid-row">
   <div class="ui-grid-col-2">
    <h:outputText value="Address :" />
  </p:column>  
  <div class="ui-grid-col-4">
    <p:outputLabel value="#{bean.address}" />  
  </div>
</div>
```