# How can I change column width of panel grid in PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am working with Java EE and PrimeFaces. How can I change the column width of a panel grid in PrimeFaces?
Is there an example ?

Comment: Post the code you have tried.

Answer (score 34):

You can qualify your columns inside the panelGrid using columnClasses. The following code sets different width and stick the cells content aligned to the top-side.

```xml
<h:panelGrid columns="2" style="width: 100%" columnClasses="forty-percent top-alignment, sixty-percent top-alignment">
```

```
.forty-percent {
     width: 40%;
}

.sixty-percent {
     width: 60%;
}

.top-alignment {
     vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: If you have mutiple columns you can also specify width ratio of a column without custom css like this `<p:panelGrid columns="4" columnClasses="ui-grid-col-2, ui-grid-col-4, ui-grid-col-2, ui-grid-col-4" layout="grid">...  </p:panelGrid>`

Comment: I like more the answer from @NwawelAIroume as it sticks with the CSS framework and doesn't add any extra CSS (which maybe one day break responsiveness).

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar problem and here is my solution:

```
<p:panelGrid style="width:100%"> # notice that I do not define columns attribute in p:panelGrid!!
    <f:facet name="header"> # header
        <p:row> # p:row and p:column are obligatory to use since we do not define columns attribute!
            <p:column colspan="2"> # here I use colspan=2, coz I have 2 columns in the body
                Title
            </p:column>
        </p:row>
    </f:facet>

    <p:row>
        <p:column style="width:150px"> # define width of a column
            Column 1 content
        </p:column>
        <p:column> # column 2 will fill the rest of the space
            Column 2 content
        </p:column>
    </p:row>

    <f:facet name="footer"> # similar as header
        <p:row>
            <p:column colspan="2">
                Footer content
            </p:column>
        </p:row>
    </f:facet>
</p:panelGrid>
```

So as you can see, the main difference is that you do **not** define **columns** attribute in *p:panelGrid*. In header and footer you have to use *p:row* and *p:column*, and in my case I also have to use colspan=2 since in body we have 2 columns.

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 7):

Have you considered the style attribute ? 
Example :

```
<p:panelGrid columns="2" style="width: 50px">
```

Otherwise, for columns :

```
<p:column style="width:50px">
```

Refer to this thread : [how can I adjust width of <p:column> in <p:panelGrid>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608414/how-can-i-adjust-width-of-pcolumn-in-ppanelgrid)

Comment: thanks Gloserio, but it still not working : the width of a one column  is relative to the content in this column; also <h:outputLabel> in the first column is not aligned with the <p:inputText> in the second column

Comment: You should maybe post your code and what you expect from it for further help.

Comment: @Akheloes `<p:panelGrid columns="2" style="width: 50px">` won't work (be it `px` or `%` btw) -- the rendered table still remains as large as the screen