# How to fix the column width of <p:panelGrid>?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I am working on JSF application in that 
*I am just having a doubt in adjusting the column width* in `panelGrid`.

**My code is :**

```
<p:panelGrid id="grid" columns="2" cellpadding="5"  styleClass="panelGrid"
    style="border:none;margin:0 auto;width:500px;"   >  
    <p:column style="width:250px">
        <h:outputText value="To :" />
    </p:column>    
    <p:column style="width:250px">
        <h:outputText value="#{bean.name}" />
    </p:column>    
    <p:column style="width:250px">
        <h:outputText value="Address :" />
    </p:column>  
    <p:column style="width:250px">
        <p:outputLabel value="#{bean.address}" />  
    </p:column>
</p:panelGrid>
```

Here I want to fix the width if first column for `250px`, so I mentioned

`<p:column style="width:250px">`

I tried

- [how can I adjust width of <p:column> in <p:panelGrid>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608414/how-can-i-adjust-width-of-pcolumn-in-ppanelgrid)
- [How can I change column width of panel grid in PrimeFaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16776631/how-can-i-change-column-width-of-panel-grid-in-primefaces)

But it is not working, column width is varying depend upon second column. Can anybody say why it is happening? Or suggest any other way to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest you to use both `<p:row />` and `<p:column />` as it is described in [Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/panelGrid.xhtml). With `<p:row />` I managed simmilar css problem to work. Like this:

```
<p:panelGrid id="grid" columns="2" cellpadding="5"  styleClass="panelGrid" style="border:none;margin:0 auto;width:500px;"   >  
   <p:row>
      <p:column style="width:250px">
         <h:outputText value="To :" />
      </p:column>    
      <p:column style="width:250px">
          <h:outputText value="#{bean.name}" />
      </p:column> 
   </p:row>
   <p:row>
       <p:column style="width:250px">
        <h:outputText value="Address :" />
      </p:column>  
      <p:column style="width:250px">
        <p:outputLabel value="#{bean.address}" />  
      </p:column>
   </p:row>
  </p:panelGrid>
```

Comment: Ya thanks for your consideration.. may i know what difference you feel after the use of `<p:row>`, because its working without use of that too

Comment: I've just wanted to define rowspan and colspan and it was obvious choice.

Comment: @miroslav_mijajlovic for a clean code you can specify columnClasses attribute in panelgrid to define each ratio of columns and place only components inside panelgrid without having to borry about row and column tag here is an example `<p:panelGrid columns="4" columnClasses="ui-grid-col-2, ui-grid-col-4, ui-grid-col-2, ui-grid-col-4" layout="grid">`

Answer (score 1):

It's not very advisable to use fixed width. I suggest you use ui-grid-col css class as described in [primefaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/grid.xhtml) .

```
<div class="ui-grid ui-grid-responsive">
 <div class="ui-grid-row">
  <div class="ui-grid-col-3">
     <h:outputText value="To :" />
  </div>    
  <div class="ui-grid-col-3">
      <h:outputText value="#{bean.name}" />
  </div> 
</div>
<div class="ui-grid-row">
   <div class="ui-grid-col-3">
    <h:outputText value="Address :" />
  </p:column>  
  <div class="ui-grid-col-3">
    <p:outputLabel value="#{bean.address}" />  
  </div>
</div>
```